# Require_once no ubunto não funciona e não retorna erro

Tags: php

Olá, eu uso o codigo abaixo no windows e funciona perfeitamente, porem quando eu uso no ubunto, o único erro que retorna é `GET http://site.com/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`, já no windows funciona perfeitamente.

index.php

```
include 'home.php'
```

home.php

```
require_once DIR_FUNCS.'func.php';
```

Comment: Qual é o valor de `DIR_FUNCS`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss `define ("DIR_FUNCS",'./'funcs/');`, eu já tentei colocar o caminho direto `/var/www/site/funcs/func.php`, mas não funcionou da mesma forma.

Comment: Não tem erro de sintaxe aí, não? O que seria `'` antes de `funcs`?

Comment: Corrigindo, `define ("DIR_FUNCS",'./funcs/');`, coloquei sem querer na hora de responder.

Comment: Já tentou inserir os parenteses: `require_once(...)`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Já, não resultou em nada.

Comment: onde voce esta definindo  DIR_FUNCS? tenta so para teste no lugar de DIR_FUNCS.'func.php' colocar (_ _ DIR_ _.'/funcs/func.php') <-"obs:remove os espacos entre _ _ DIR _ _ o site nao esta deixando junto" isso se a pasta funcs ficar na mesma pasta que home.php

Comment: Eu estava fazendo uns testes e retornou um erro novo `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`, não sei se isso ajuda.

Comment: erro 500 costuma ser erro de permissão

Comment: Realmente, dei as permissões necessárias, e voltou para esse erro `GET http://site.com/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`. Usando o xampp continua dando o erro, porem funciona do mesmo jeito.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver colocando o caminho absoluto de tudo.

Comment: Não acho que seja uma boa solução, experimentou os comandos indicados pelo @Robson gomes de jesus ?

Comment: Se o problema for realmente esse, defina um caminho `root` para o aplicativo.

Comment: @Edilson como eu poderia fazer isso ??

Comment: @lazyFox Tentei sim.

Answer (score 0):

pelo termina vá ate a pasta onde esta o projeto
exemplo:
cd /var/www/site
certifique-se que esta como root (obs: sudo su para se logar como root)
aplique os comandos

```
 find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

e

```
 find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

caso continue tenta find * no lugar de find .

tentai e fala no que deu, creio que vá resolver